App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next) must be compatible with
App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next) must be compatible with Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::handle($request, Closure $next, ...$guards) error
See video and get resolution https://youtu.be/tr1XquukSew
https://youtu.be/tr1XquukSew
To see this video solve your issue and get update.
